# Scala type parameter with multiple types as result of function

Tags: scala

I'm trying to implement a project where there are traits:

```
`trait Checkable`

`trait Closeable`
```

and a class:

```
`case class DBConnection (url: String) extends Checkable with Closeable`
```

and a function

```
`def generateConnection[T <: Checkable with Closeable](url: String): T = DBConnection(url)`
```

On compiling the above code, it generates error:

```
`Expression of type DBConnection doesn't conform to expected type T_`
```

What can I do to solve this issue?

I can use the expression:

```
`DBConnection(url).asInstanceOf[T]`
```

But I don't think it's the best practice

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your method says it would return `T`, where `T` is a subtype of `Checkable with Closeable`. But then it returns a `DBConnection`. What if the user invoked this method parameterized with `MyCustomDBConnection`? She would expect that same type as a result, and instead she would receive your `DBConnection`.

You are making a promise you can't keep. It's better to revoke the opportunity to set the type T, and only promise that you'll return a `Checkable with Closeable`. Then everything should compile fine.

```
def generateConnection(url: String): Checkable with Closeable = DBConnection(url)
```

If you still want to parameterize your method with `T`, then you will have to make a typeclass which would provide different implementations for different variants of `T`. You can't just return a `DBConnection` every time, because what's the point of `T` then.